# Grant roles to mongo users via rails

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I am trying to assign roles to mongo users through rails controller.
I know that we can assign roles to users as mentioned [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/user-management/), but there we need to update the whole user. So is there any way to run a query similar to `grantRole` directly through the rails controller?

Comment: You can put the invocation into the rails controller.

Comment: Here I need to run the query similar to db.grantRolesToUsers(). Can you please explain a bit more with example code snippet?.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

db.grantRolesToUser  is a [shell helper](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.grantRolesToUser/). You can find out how it is implemented by typing its name in the shell but not invoking it:

```
MongoDB Enterprise ruby-driver-rs:PRIMARY> db.grantRolesToUser
function(username, roles, writeConcern) {
    var cmdObj = {
        grantRolesToUser: username,
        roles: roles,
        writeConcern: writeConcern ? writeConcern : _defaultWriteConcern
    };
    var res = this.runCommand(cmdObj);
    if (!res.ok) {
        throw _getErrorWithCode(res, res.errmsg);
    }
}
```

You can see that it uses `runCommand`.

The Ruby mechanism for running arbitrary commands is [documented here](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/master/tutorials/ruby-driver-database-tasks/#arbitrary-comands).

You would then do something like:

```
 client.database.command(grantRolesToUser: username, roles: ['foo'])
```

To get the client instance, use `Foo.collection.client` where `Foo` is a Mongoid model class.